# How to know which call the current callback is for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitch

I have a loop making several ajax calls to an API. For each call there would be callback. 
The problem happen when there's an error and no data is returned, I am not able to know which call made that error.

How do I detect the call that caused this error inside the callback function? 
here's part of the code:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {

if ($.inArray(channels[i], livenow) > -1) {

  continue;
}
this.chname = channels[i]; //this is the channel name
Twitch.api({
  method: 'channels/' + this.chname
}, function(error, list) {
//insdie this callback 
//chname may have been changed when we received the callback
  console.log(this.chname + '===>');
```

now, I am not sure what value of chname was called in the API to make the error.
when there's no errors, I depend on the data returned from the server to know the callback was a result of which call. when the server return an error, I am not able to know which call this callback is for.

Comment: Can you show the API calls - we cannot help really without seeing code

Comment: The callback is also exposed to the original request object. You can use that to get the details of the request.

Comment: I make a call in a loop and by the time I receive the callback I am not sure which call caused the error

Comment: @emissary it won't help as inside the loop the variable would be changed to the last element in the array before the 1st callback is fired. then if callbacks are called with errors it would access the variable twice and it would read the last value as it was the last element in the array not the other two that caused the error.

Comment: @Tamer https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w4nre8vk/1/ ?

Comment: @Boaz how do i access the original request object for the current callback ?

Comment: here's the code, the function is called getChannels
http://codepen.io/TamerMarzouk/pen/VabQvP

Comment: @Tamer Your question appears to be about the Twitch Javascript SDK and not about jQuery at all. You should change your question in accordance. It doesn't seem the Twitch `api` method passes the original request object to the callback. Alternatively, you can use closures inside the loop to isolate each request's details.

Comment: Thanks @Boaz, using a closure solved it. I used an array for to save each call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @boaz suggested, using closure would keep the environment for each call.
So, the code would look like :

```
function mycall(chname) {

function twitchcall() {

Twitch.api({
  method: 'channels/' + chname
}, function(error, list) {
 //callback code would be able to access chname when the twitch call was made
});
};
return twitchcall;}
```

now to use the closure above, we write the following inside the loop

```
//now to use it inside the loop
calls[i] = mycall(xchname);
calls[i]();
```

for a full example http://codepen.io/TamerMarzouk/pen/VabQvP